# Raspberry is stuck at boot

Tags: boot, script

I am working for some time now on my raspberry and I think I messed everything up.

I have a program say `./test`

In order to start this at boot I added to my `/etc/rc.local` file the following:

```
sleep 5
/var/www/test.sh > /dev/null
```

I messed up changing a while loop in my `./test`.

I've changed the sleep in the while loop to `sleep 0`.

Now the raspberry is stuck at boot. And probably because the CPU is maxed now...

The last message is:

```
[info] Checking for tables which need an upgrade, are corrupt or were not closed cleanly..
```

So is there any way I can stop it? 
Ctrl->C does nothing..

**Edit:**

1. I have connected a screen, a wlan dongle and a keyboard. (Removing everything but screen doesn't effect anything)
2. The code of `test.sh` is not special. The thing is, I have a do while loop, with some if statements and a sleep at the end. But I removed the sleep part so the CPU will go mental.
3. [image]
4. If i put it in my other computer, I have to fragment it before I can use it, so that's no good. Will take it to work tomorrow and take a look there. If I can access the `rc.local` file, it is solved for sure!
5. I have waited for more than 10 minutes, but nothing changed.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites

Comment: Please share the code of test.sh. Please also tell how long you have been waiting for startup. How are you monitoring startup? Do you have a screen and keyboard connected? Do you run X? Do you have an opportunity to take a picture of the screen when it's stuck?

Comment: A simple thing to do would be to put the SD card in another machine, and remove the entry in rc.local.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't say what operating system you have on your other computer, but you talk about "If i put it in my other computer i have to fragment it before i can use it", I assume that it is Windows.

Solution: put your SD card in another *LINUX* computer. The Linux part of my answer is very important, because it will not do any nonsense (fragmenting/corrupting/...) like Windows does, because Windows doesn't know anything about the Linux filesystem on the Pi.

Then you just edit `/etc/rc.local` or `/var/www/test.sh`, whatever it takes to fix your problem.

If you don't want to experiment with Linux on your other computer, download a Live cd and burn that to a dvd or usb stick. I can recomment Ubuntu, but any other distro is ok.